# need to separate URL to path and params

Tags: url

I have an URL link to this.

```
http://localhost:4200/tab/event/eventcard?id=recV364lxjTat9lBQ
```

I need to get `tab/event/eventcard` and `recV364lxjTat9lBQ` separately from angular. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem using this code snippet.

```
parameters = new URL(your_URL_here);
```